Python "turtle" module not found specifically in VS Code
I am running Linux Mint, the problem is that "turtle", which has to be a built-in module is not found in both VS Code and VS Codium, even though I have imported it. The strangest thing is that turtle works when I am running my script through linux's terminal, IDLE or Geany. Everything worked perfectly on my Windows machine.
Other libraries, such as numpy or sympy are imported and working perfectly.
This is a sample script:
import turtle

turtle.pendown()
for i in range(50):
    turtle.forward(100)
turtle.mainloop()

And this is the error:
sh-5.2$ /bin/python /home/testydungeon/VSCodium/test/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testydungeon/VSCodium/test/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'turtle'

I have tried to install turtle through both IDE with pip and through terminal with apt-get. I have also tried to install tkinter as it seems to have some dependencies with turtle. Import of tkinter also doesn't work btw, giving pretty much the same error.
Python versions: Terminal: 3.10.12 VSCode: 3.11.9

Terminal: 3.10.12   VSCode: 3.11.9

Please [edit] that into the question. Thanks. Sounds like you need to sync up those python versions, or install turtle on the VSCode version. Canonical: Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?, version specific to VSCode (but on ubuntu): ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Turtle'

I have already tried methods from the answers you sent me. Didn't work. Talking about synchronising versions, should I degrade the version I have on VSCode or update the one on my machine?

Up to you, but if you want to just get it working, point VSCode to the one that already works on the command line. Or just code in VSCode but run on the terminal version that works.

check if you have command python3.11 in terminal and check if you cam import turtle when you run python3.11. Normally Python should be installed with tkinter and turtle but once I saw Ubuntu Server which had Python without tkinter. If you use apt search python3 then sometimes you may see python3.11-tk as separate module and you may try to install it using apt install ...

Please check the python interpreter by shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the python interpreter which you installed the package in.

@furas yes, I can use this command in terminal of linux and importing turtle works perfectly. The problem is with VSCode only.

@MingJie-MSFT only interpreters I have installed in VSCode are a bunch of "Python 3.11.9 64-bit" and I use the one which is marked as "Recommended"
